# haxm emulator is runing but without any display or response

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, emulation, haxm

***software*** : AndroidStudio V.1.3.x & Windows 10 & jdk V.1.8.x

and as an important thing haxm logcat system don't show me any special log !

[image]

and the base issue pic

[image]

notice:i also trying to set 0 variable for high and wight (it's don't work for me )